Console says "chrome" is undefined in "chrome.offscreen.createObject" in content.js file
I am trying to make a Chrome extension which calls an offscreen file from content.js to play an audio file. However, running it in Chrome, the console window throws this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createDocument')
    at checkForVideoElement (content.js:28:30)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (VM304 content.js:7:21)

manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Custom",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "templates/popup.html",
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo.png",
        "32": "images/logo.png",
        "48": "images/logo.png",
        "128": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "offscreen"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://www.netflix.com/watch/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.netflix.com/watch/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

content.js:
// Try to find the video element immediately
if (!checkForVideoElement()) {
    // If not found, use a mutation observer to watch for changes
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                if (checkForVideoElement()) {
                    // Stop observing once the video element is found
                    observer.disconnect();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Start observing the document body for added nodes
    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

function checkForVideoElement() {
    var video = document.querySelector("video");
    if (video) {
        console.log(video);

        if (video.currentTime <= 60) {
            console.log("Video found less than 60s");
            // creating offscreen document to play the custom Tudum sound
            // chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
            //     url: chrome.runtime.getURL("offscreen.html"),
            //     reasons: ["AUDIO_PLAYBACK"],
            //     justification: "Playing Custom Sound"
            // }, () => {
            //     chrome.runtime.sendMessage("playCustomSound");
            // });
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


offscreen.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Play Sound</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="../scripts/offscreen.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

offscreen.js:
console.log("Offscreen script loaded");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Offscreen script received message:", message);

    if (message.action === "playSound") {
        playSound();
    }
});

function playSound() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("Sound", function (result) {
        let audio = result.Sound;
        if (audio) {
            console.log("Audio found");
            // Convert the data URI to a Blob
            fetch(audio)
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {
                    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const audioElement = new Audio(audioUrl);
                    audioElement.play().then(() => {
                        console.log("Audio played successfully");
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error converting audio data:", error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log("Audio not found");
        }
    });
}

adding code
console.log(chrome)
console.log(chrome.offscreen)

actually verifies that it is the latter object which is undefined. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

The reason why chrome.storage.local.get() was working earlier in your content script (content.js) but is now not working may be due to changes in Chrome's security policies or extension manifest requirements.

@RavinaSarda, I just updated the post to reflect my findings - it's chrome.offscreen which is undefined not the chrome object itself. And the "previous version" of my script was made just this morning anyway :)

Content scripts can't use most of chrome API including offscreen API, but there's no need to use it anyway: just play the file directly in the content script. If the file is inside your extension then declare it in web_accessible_resources and just set the audio's src to chrome.runtime.getURL('file.mp3'). P.S. Remove watch/ from matches because this site uses the same page internally, meaning the content script won't run if you first opened the main netflix page and then went to a watch page.

The chrome.offscreen API is not a standard Chrome extension API and may not be supported or available in all environments. You can either use a Background Script or Web Audio API . You can leverage the Web Audio API directly within your content script or background script to play audio.

@woxxom thank you for your comment! Unfortunately my extension mutes the current tab in background.js, goes to content.js for the checkForVideoElement function to play a sound, and then unmutes again in background.js. Therefore, I must play the sound with an offscreen element so that the sound does not get muted along with the current tab.. hope that makes sense?

Then create the offscreen document in the background script.

@woxxom, so I have tried doing that - content.js, after checking the video on the page, sends a message to background.js which further initiates the offscreen page. I believe the code is correct, but the service worker console now shows: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. Do you know why that may be?

Maybe you send the message incorrectly or too early. See also this example and if it doesn't help make a new question with the new code.

@woxxom, I've created a new question with the updated code. I'd really appreciate it if you could check that out! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78526053/background-script-uncaught-in-promise-error-could-not-establish-connection
