background script: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist
I am trying to create an offscreen document that plays an audio for my chrome extension. My background.js script receives a message that triggers the initiation of the offscreen document, which contains code to run an audio file uploaded by the user. Every time I run it, I get this in the service worker console:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

And upon reloading the page, I get:
Error creating offscreen document: Error: Only a single offscreen document may be created.

Here is my code:
manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Custom",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "templates/popup.html",
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo.png",
        "32": "images/logo.png",
        "48": "images/logo.png",
        "128": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "offscreen"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://www.netflix.com/watch/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.netflix.com/watch/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

content.js:
// Try to find the video element immediately
if (!checkForVideoElement()) {
    // If not found, use a mutation observer to watch for changes
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                if (checkForVideoElement()) {
                    // Stop observing once the video element is found
                    observer.disconnect();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Start observing the document body for added nodes
    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

function checkForVideoElement() {
    var video = document.querySelector("video");
    if (video) {
        console.log(video);

        if (video.currentTime <= 60) {
            console.log("Video found less than 60s");
            // asking background.js to create an offscreen document and play the sound
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage("runOffscreenTask");
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

background.js:
// Fix for crbug.com/1185241
if (typeof chrome.runtime.onMessage !== "undefined") {
    const { onMessage } = chrome.runtime;
    const { addListener } = onMessage;
    onMessage.addListener = fn => addListener.call(onMessage, (msg, sender, respond) => {
        const res = fn(msg, sender, respond);
        if (res instanceof Promise) return !!res.then(respond, console.error);
        if (res !== undefined) respond(res);
    });
}

// Re-inject content scripts on extension install/update
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
    const contentScripts = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts;
    for (const cs of contentScripts) {
        const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ url: cs.matches });
        for (const tab of tabs) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id, allFrames: cs.all_frames },
                files: cs.js,
                injectImmediately: cs.run_at === 'document_start',
            });
        }
    }
});

// Tab update listener
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === "complete" && tab.url.indexOf("netflix.com/watch/") !== -1) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { muted: true });

        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ['scripts/content.js']
        }, () => {
            console.log("Content script injected successfully");
        });

        chrome.storage.local.get("soundDuration", function (result) {
            let duration = result.soundDuration || 0;
            console.log("Duration of the sound: " + duration + "ms");
            setTimeout(() => {
                chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { muted: false });
            }, (8000 - duration));
        });
    }
});

// Message listener for offscreen task
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message === "runOffscreenTask") {
        offScreenTask();
        return true;
    }
});

async function offScreenTask() {
    await setupOffscreenDocument('offscreen.html');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("playSound");
    return true;
}

let creating; // A global promise to avoid concurrency issues
async function setupOffscreenDocument() {
    const offscreenUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("offscreen.html");
    const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({
        contextTypes: ['OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'],
        documentUrls: [offscreenUrl]
    });

    if (existingContexts.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (creating) {
        await creating;
    } else {
        creating = chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
            url: offscreenUrl,
            reasons: ["AUDIO_PLAYBACK"],
            justification: "Playing Custom Sound",
        });
        await creating;
        creating = null;
    }
}


offscreen.js:
console.log("Offscreen script loaded");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Offscreen script received message:", message);

if ('crbug.com/1185241') { // replace with a check for Chrome version that fixes the bug
    const { onMessage } = chrome.runtime, { addListener } = onMessage;
    onMessage.addListener = fn => addListener.call(onMessage, (msg, sender, respond) => {
        const res = fn(msg, sender, respond);
        if (res instanceof Promise) return !!res.then(respond, console.error);
        if (res !== undefined) respond(res);
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Offscreen script received message:", message);

    if (message.action === "playSound") {
        playSound();
    }
});

function playSound() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("Sound", function (result) {
        let audio = result.Sound;
        if (audio) {
            console.log("Audio found");
            // Convert the data URI to a Blob
            fetch(audio)
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {
                    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const audioElement = new Audio(audioUrl);
                    audioElement.play().then(() => {
                        console.log("Audio played successfully");
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error converting audio data:", error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log("Audio not found");
        }
    });
}

I am not sure how to fix the "receiving end" function, and I am confused as to why the "single offscreen" function is occurring even though I believe I have correctly implemented a setupOffscreenDocument() function in my background.js too.
I have already looked at this answer on re-injecting the content script and this answer on separating async requests from message listeners and tried my best to implement all the suggestions, but my code still doesn't work. Even reloading the page manually doesn't do anything - just shows the "single offscreen document" error.
I am very new at this, so I may have gone very obviously wrong in quite a few places!
EDIT:
updated background.js:
// Re-inject content scripts on extension install/update
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
    const contentScripts = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts;
    for (const cs of contentScripts) {
        const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ url: cs.matches });
        for (const tab of tabs) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id, allFrames: cs.all_frames },
                files: cs.js,
                injectImmediately: cs.run_at === 'document_start',
            });
        }
    }
});

// Tab update listener
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === "complete" && tab.url.indexOf("netflix.com/watch/") !== -1) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { muted: true });

        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ['scripts/content.js']
        }, () => {
            console.log("Content script injected successfully");
        });

        chrome.storage.local.get("soundDuration", function (result) {
            let duration = result.soundDuration || 0;
            console.log("Duration of the sound: " + duration + "ms");
            setTimeout(() => {
                chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { muted: false });
            }, (8000 - duration));
        });
    }
});

// Message listener for offscreen task
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message === "runOffscreenTask") {
        console.log("Received message to run offscreen task");
        offScreenTask();
        return true;
    }
});

async function offScreenTask() {
    await setupOffscreenDocument('offscreen.html');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ sound: await getSound() });
    return true;
}

async function setupOffscreenDocument() {
    try {
        await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL('offscreen.html'),
            reasons: ["AUDIO_PLAYBACK"],
            justification: "Playing Custom Sound",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        if (!error.message.startsWith('Only a single offscreen'))
            throw error;
    }
}

async function getSound() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.storage.local.get("Sound", function (result) {
            let audio = result.Sound;
            if (audio) {
                console.log("Audio found");
                resolve(audio);
            } else {
                console.log("Audio not found");
                reject("Audio not found");
            }
        });
    });
}

updated offscreen.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Offscreen script received message:", message);

    if (sound in message) {
        console.log("Playing sound:", sound);
        playSound(sound);
    }
});

function playSound(audio) {
    // Convert the data URI to a Blob
    fetch(audio)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const audioElement = new Audio(audioUrl);
            audioElement.play().then(() => {
                console.log("Audio played successfully");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error converting audio data:", error);
        });
}

Also, a screenshot of the extensions details page:



Open chrome://extensions details for your extension and see if it lists the offscreen document. If not, you've used an incorrect path. 2) The offscreen document can only use chrome.runtime messaging, it can't use chrome.storage, so you need to read it in the caller (the background script) and send the result in sendMessage. 3) Either remove the entire crbug.com/1185241  block because you're not using it or remove return true because you don't need it. Also it should be used at the beginning of offscreen.js not inside the listener.


Simplify your setupOffscreenDocument as shown in How to fix error: only a single offscreen document may be created?

@woxxom I have updated the document as you said, and I do not see the offscreen.html document anywhere on the details page (as you can see in the screenshot I have added to my post). I have updated my post with the new code but I am still getting the same error.

It means the path is incorrect e.g. offscreen.html is in a different folder or there's an error inside this html.
